# Boton eliminar con Javascript en aplicativo de ASP.NET

Tags: javascript, asp.net

Tengo un aplicativo que guarda en una base de datos y tiene un botón para eliminar, ya realicé la función de eliminar y que pida confirmación, pero cuando se le da al botón cancelar igualmente elimina el registro. La funcion que tengo es esta:

```
<script>
    function confirmDel() {
        var agree = confirm("¿Realmente desea eliminarlo? ");
        if (agree) return true;
        return false;
    }
</script>
```

Y la llamo en el botón así:

```
<a onclick="confirmDel();" href="@Url.Action("Eliminar", "Agenda", new { id = contacto.Id })" class="btn btn-danger">Eliminar</a>
```

Espero contar con su ayuda.

Comment: Pon la validación en una sola línea: `if(confirm("¿Realmente desea eliminarlo? ")) return true; else return false;`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Utiliza el metodo `Event#preventDefault()` para evitar que te redireccione si se preciona cancel.

Aqui un ejemplo:

```js
function confirmDel(e) {
    var agree = confirm("¿Realmente deseas visitar este sitio?");
    
    if (agree == false) 
      e.preventDefault(); 
}
```

```html
<a onclick="confirmDel(event)" href="https://es.stackoverflow.com">Visitar stackoverflow en español?</a>
```

Fijate que se tuvo que enviar el objeto `event` como parametro en el `onclick`. `preventDefault()` evita que el control ejecute si comportamiento por defecto.

Comment: Gracias por responder, ya lo hice como tu dices pero sigue eliminando al darle cancelar

Comment: Como pusiste el link y el elemento a? lo pusiste como indique?

Comment: ah si sr, me faltaba algo asi me funciono perfecto mil gracias

Answer (score 0):

```
<a  href="@Url.Action("Eliminar", "Agenda", new {Id = contacto.Id }, new {@class="btn btn-danger",onclick="confirmDel();"})>Eliminar</a>
```

Prueba esto

Comment: Gracias por responder, al hacerlo asi no ejecuta el script sino que elimina directamente sin preguntar..

Comment: El código es el mismo que el del OP, solo cambiaste el orden de la función de JS

Comment: pero y si eso es lo que tiene el código que esta mal que tu quieres que ponga